# Base-ically god

Tags: code-golf, number, base-conversion

### Story

The god of base is opening heaven’s gate for mortals to join the base party. You, as one of the believers, want to follow their steps to ascend to heaven.

But not everyone can get in.

The god posts this question to let you prove you are worthy of their party.

### Task

You will get 2 inputs

- First being `X` which is a non-negative integer in base 10.
- Second being `base` which is a list of bases to iterate over.
- **bases will always be positive integers which in range of 1~10**
- The base will contain at least one not `1` base

You will need to present(print) `X` in the form of iterating bases.

Example:

```
X ,[base] -> ans

6 ,[2] -> 110
It has only 1 base in base list, thus it converts number into base2

6 ,[2,4] -> 30
First base is 2, so 6%2=0 is the first digit and (6-0)/2 =3 is forwarded to next base.
Second base is 4, so 3%4=3 is the second digit and there is no remaining.

30 ,[2,3] -> 2100
First two digits come from 30%2=0, 15%3=0, with 15/3=5 is passed to next base,
which loops back to 2 => 5%2 = 1,pass 2=> 2%3 = 2

10 ,[9,2] -> 11
20 ,[3,4,5] -> 122
0 ,[any bases] -> 0
```

### Rules

- No standard loopholes
- Input, output in any reasonable, convenient format is accepted.

The god requires short code—they will give access to the shortest code in each language. Fulfill their task to ascend!

Comment: can we take X in the array like  [X,*bases] ?

Comment: @Razetime Any convenience format is allowed :)

Comment: Note: giving all ones for the base will never terminate for nonzero input. (Mixing ones with higher numbers is fine)

Comment: Can I take the list of bases in reverse order?

Comment: @Bubbler In any convenience format :)

Comment: If a base is greater than 10, how should I represent a digit of 10 or higher?

Comment: @Bubbler didn't see that coming, for sake of answers below, I am limiting it to 1~10

Comment: what is base 1 for? Say, what is expected output for `42, [1]`?

Comment: @tsh I've edited the question so that there will contain at least 1 not `1` base

Comment: @okie wouldn't 42, [1] just be 42 0s? Or 42 1s rather

Comment: @Cruncher If there exist such a case( which I fixed the question to exclude) it would have infinity 0

Comment: Hmmm, somehow I don't get what's the goal even after reading part 1 - could you maybe add a formula ?

Comment: @Programmer, The formula is hard to explain, I think you can look at answer below to understand more.

Answer (score 6):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 8 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

A re-implementation of [Jonah's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224736/43319).

```
10⊥⌽⍤⍴⊤⊣
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=MzR41LX0Uc/eR71LHvVuedS15FHXYgA&f=M1NIUzDiMgOROiZcxgZghjGXIYhhqWPEZQRiGOuY6JhygViGOkBZAA&i=AwA&r=tryAPL&l=apl-dyalog&m=train&n=f)

An anonymous tacit infix function taking `base` on the right and `X` on the left.

`⊣` the value `X`

`⊤` represented in base…

`⌽⍤⍴` reversed `base` cyclically-repeated until length `X`

`10⊥` evaluated as base-10

Comment: Bah, ninja'd while fixing my answer D:

Answer (score 4):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <sup><s>13 11</s></sup> 10 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
╨¬ª₧}ÄM☻☻.
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=d0aaa69e7d8e4d02022e&i=0,%5B345%5D%0A6+,%5B2%5D%0A6+,%5B2,4%5D%0A30,+%5B2,3%5D%0A10,+%5B9,2%5D%0A20,%5B3,4,5%5D%0A&m=2)

Having another stack based language to compete with gave some golfing motivation.

### Explanation

```
n^*{|%mr$A|b
n^*               repeat bases X+1 times
   {  m           map to 
    |%            divmod(puts quotient on stack for next iteration)
       r          reverse
        $         join to string
         A|b      interpret as base 10
```

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>12</sup> 11 bytes

```
10#.|.@$#:[
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DQ2U9Wr0HFSUraL/a3KlJmfkKxgppNUpmMHYxiCesQGEawmRNIRyjRVMFExBAkZQAXMFC6AQUMDgPwA)

<sup>-1 after reading Adam's APL answer and realizing I could get rid of the `~`.   Other than that, we both found the exact same answer.</sup>

J has a mixed base primitive that does the heavy lifting `#:`.

- `|.@$~` Repeat the base as man times as the number we're converting, and then reverse.  Extra left digits will become 0, and this ensures we always have enough digits.
- `#:]` Using the previous result, convert the input using mixed base.
- `10#.` Convert back to a base 10 number to remove the extra zeros.

Comment: mixed base conversion ftw

Comment: You can take the input in reverse, so `|.@` is not necessary.

Comment: @Bubbler If you look at my edit history, you'll see I tried that  but it doesn't always work :)  Eg, this test case `20 ,[3,4,5] -> 122`

Comment: @Jonah Oh, didn't notice that.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 41 bytes

A massive improvement from my previous solution, based on a clever observation by [@att](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81203/att), to use the fact that bases are \$ \le 10 \$.

```python
f=lambda x,y,*b:x and 10*f(x//y,*b,y)+x%y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3LDoIwEEX3/YrZGFoctQ80kQR/xLgoUWOTgo0Wha/HKb52c86duROGeLm2ZhzPlbdNfbTQ44B5XfZg2yMomZ95v1olhYOY97NhfF6cP4EqGbg2IFy7GKBKcxe5WN6Dd5FnsNhBJhi1QU3p6WE9pxUyn33v7pE3NpCN7xJBYbgRcnqJkNfi48cN4F4fUqVSkk2ExcRGMiMnNhNrJSVTyWzxe8F0YoMFrt9Ga5aMQrr6Wcn0/4t8AQ)

#### [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 48 bytes

Outputs the number as a list of digits. A couple of bytes are needed to handle the edge cases where \$ X = 0 \$.

```python
f=lambda x,y,*b:x//y and f(x//y,*b,y)+[x%y]or[x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3LDoIwEEX3/YrZGFodtQ800QR/hLAoUSNJgUar0q/HKai7OefO3PEx3PrOjOO1cLatzxYGjLisj8N2G8F2Z7jyNJLCKFblsIhVfy@HanzfGncBdWTQdB6hfwYPRZqfgYvNw7sm8AzWJ8gEo1KoKb28rOO0Qua775pH4K31ZMNcIij0d0JOnxGWtfj6cQ9Y6ipVKiXZRJhPbCQzcmIzsVZSMpXMAX8XTCc2mONuNlqzZBTS1d/KDw)

Comment: [46 bytes](https://tio.run/##RY3bDgExEIbv@xRzI9o16AEJCS8iLlpsNKnVUKenX9Pu4m6@759/Jr7T6dKYtq3XwZ7dwYJFh9V@xe106sA2B1CyqguRRifEyA5c@zz5cAS1YuCbiHC5pwjrPN8TF5NbDD7xIYw3MBQMXgiO0uPDBk4rZPr94G@Jn20km7ojgsJ4JeQ1p1rlRO/bBeBW7/JJpSQrhLPCRjIjC5vCWknJVDZL/DaYzmxwhvPOaM2yUUitn5VM/7/IDw) with the guarantee that bases are <=10

Comment: @att Clever, thanks! I think, because the return value is an integer, we can now ignore the edge case and save 5 more bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
sиvy‰`s}JRï
```

I have the feeling this can be shorter, but I'm a bit rusty on code-golfing.

Takes the list of bases as first input and integer \$X\$ as second input.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@/@MKOsspHDRsSimu9gg6v//8/2kjHOJbL2AAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWWCy9EFxf@LL@woq3zUsCGhuNYr6PD6/zr/o6OjjWJ1zGJ1FIAMHRME0zhWx9gAzLbUAaowhLCNdUx0TGN1jKC8WB0DqHILEDMWAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
s        # Swap the two (implicit) inputs, so the stack is bases-list, integer X
 и       # Repeat the bases-list X amount of times
  v      # Loop over each value `y` in this list:
   y‰    #  Divmod `y` ([v//y, v%y]), which will use the second (implicit) input-integer
         #  X as value in the very first iteration
     `   #  Pop this list, and push both separated to the stack
      s  #  Swap their order, so the v//y is at the top, as value for the next iteration
  }J     # After the loop: join all integers on the stack together
    R    # Reverse it
     ï   # And cast it to an integer to remove any leading 0s
         # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: Welcome back! I hope all is well.

Comment: @Razetime Hi there. :) Thanks, but I'm not back full-time. I used to code-golf A LOT during work when I was waiting for copies; compilations; build runs; installations; etc., or because I simply was fed up with the current bug/feature I was working on. But since I switched jobs two months ago I barely have those kind of waiting times in between work anymore since everything here is a lot more efficient and thus faster. So you won't see me as often as before for sure, but I might answer a challenge here and there when I feel like it. :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 57 bytes

```python
f=lambda x,a,*b,j=0:x and f(x//a,*b[1:],a,j=[])+[x%a]or j
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcxBCoMwEIXhfU8xm0JiBzTGCgo5SchiREIbahRxkZ4@TdMu4vZ7j397H4/VyxitetEyzQQBCasJnWrGAORnsCzU9de0GE0andKG33S4kll3cHHbn/5glvUIlW4N55ezIHQlyuavslSRdUA4BdqsMhUQ7uWQXaT3LxM/)

-5 bytes borrowing the idea from Arnauld to use splat.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 43 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,[b,...a])=>n&&+f(n/b|0,[...a,b])+[n%b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc7NCsIwEATgu0@RiyWha5psquKhvkjYQ1NbqZRErHjy3WME/wjOcfhg5tTe2rm7jOfryodDH@PQcA/WgZSyJdHsfVGUA/eVuyuwzxIcidL6paPYBT@HqZdTOPKBb4BZJJYiBKsqprVa/BFQ01uYHJi0gWA@ALXKiU5kB0jflQxgAgZqWNMLIGZCpRvbn6MqPgA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 41 bytes

```hs
0?_=0
n?(h:t)=mod n h+10*div n h?(t++[h])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY1BboMwEEX3PsUoygLKEI1NUqlNDKvuegOEGiLcYsXYFbFS4PLUBLW7/57@/Gnr21UZM89UfEhitojaVx/LzjVgoU04PTX6vsQi8klStlU8d7W2snEMSosXdNUp/XF9c9t9auNVH52t829GdedNmm/i0zb/Uv5dW8XAKA@D7FUdto/jGi7HaQ1h77vX1kdDMUo54YAjTjGD5dv8DKWoIM2Bc2IL4P6BGbGMFsweKDgR40G84F@diYAZ7vGwCiFYEBzDyb@kXw)

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
ê├Ä_]─k\É‼%/]xy
```

First input is \$X\$, all other inputs are the values in the bases-list.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///wqkdT5hxuiY99NKUhO@Zw56OGPar6sRWV//@b6RhxAbGOCZexAZAy5jI00LEEihkZ6BjrmOiYchnoGHKB2BYA)

**Explanation:**

```python
ê         # Push all inputs as an integer-list
 ├        # Pop its first item (the integer X), and push it to the stack
  Ä       # Loop that many times, using a single character as inner code-block:
   _      #  Duplicate the list at the top of the stack
  ]       # After the loop, wrap all list on the stack into a list
   ─      # Flatten this list of lists of integers
    k     # Push the first integer-input X again
     \    # Swap, so the list we created earlier is at the top of the stack
      É   # For-each over this list, using three characters as inner code-block:
       ‼  #  Apply the following two commands separated on the top value:
        % #   Modulo
        / #   Integer-divide
      ]   # After the loop, wrap all values on the stack into a list
       x  # Reverse this list
        y # Join it together, and convert it to an integer, removing leading 0s
          # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>38</s> 39 bytes

```
#>=#2&&#0[⌊#/#2⌋,##3,#2]||#~Mod~#2&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7X9nOVtlITU3ZIPpRT5eyvrLRo55uHWVlYx1lo9iaGuU63/yUOqCC/wFFmXkl0cq6dmkODsqxanXByYl5ddVc1WY6RrU6YErHBMQwNgCyjEEsQwMdS4ikkYGOsY6JjimIbQAVAlJctf8B)

Input `[X, bases..]`. Returns an `Or` of digits.

`MixedRadix` exists and would perform the task easily (in conjunction with `IntegerDigits`), but it isn't cyclic.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 23 bytes

```
M|&J/GhHagJ.<H1%GhH]GgF
```

[Test suite](http://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=M%7C%26J%2FGhHagJ.%3CH1%25GhH%5DGgF&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=6%2C+%5B2%5D%0A6%2C+%5B2%2C4%5D%0A30%2C+%5B2%2C3%5D%0A10%2C+%5B9%2C2%5D%0A20%2C+%5B3%2C4%2C5%5D%0A0%2C+%5B1337%5D&debug=0)

Direct translation of [dingledooper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/88546/dingledooper)['s Python 3 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224746/78186).

### Pyth, 25 bytes

```
AQWG=+k%G@HZ~/G@H~hZ)|_k0
```

[Test suite](http://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=AQWG%3D%2Bk%25G%40HZ%7E%2FG%40H%7EhZ%29%7C_k0&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=6%2C+%5B2%5D%0A6%2C+%5B2%2C4%5D%0A30%2C+%5B2%2C3%5D%0A10%2C+%5B9%2C2%5D%0A20%2C+%5B3%2C4%2C5%5D%0A0%2C+%5B1337%5D&debug=0)

Naïve solution. Surprised it's only 2 bytes longer...

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>66</s> <s>59</s> <s>58</s> 55 bytes

*Edit: -7 bytes thanks to [att](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81203/att)'s comment on [dingledooper's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224746/95126): previous version uselessly worried about handling bases >10*

```r
f=function(n,b)`if`(n,10*f(n%/%b,c(b[-1],b))+n%%b,0)[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc7BCsIwDMbxu08xkEKrEZN0DjzsScZwtqzQS4W5PX9tp2Bu4f@Djyw5rvPycM/33OfQhy35Nb6STuDMFMNUDsJT0EldlQOv3XChsZg5J1UCmoHG/4TugE1zbIjwIKPXDK2pYiVY3MXuwoTSqNr9Z0RCuIqFFm5fYxaI5d1aMX8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 82 bytes

```c
a;c;i;r;f(x,b,l)int*b;{for(a=1,r=i=0;x;x/=c)c=b[i++%l],r+=x%c*a,a*=10,x-=x%c;x=r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZNhb5swEIa/51eckJAwOCoYmNS63j5M@xUJmsCYzipLKxxp1iL@@jIbA8Fpo5DLvY/f0/l08P0L59drTTmVdKBdpHGDeyRP57ihl@5tiGqW4YFJllJN9QPjiLPmIJMk7Cs8JEyHPK5xHbMsxXpvU6rZQMfr@2CKRLZQjcEE6BFcwFQEK4IEBik14Rl6CkkiEUyOLgpCFbYBjuS3AEPwFAQIQ32QFaIw7qz1dy1PEdpddmA@VjgLdU4Plal4ISNdpWyWcLERySLmGzF34iPe2gsn5rjA5UYuPXnpIZ6YcmzqB7seXCAu5C4ULmzsU/6zd3Yl/4q3LpqqoIc5i12KYUMzn2Y@JT4lPs19mvu08Gnh09KnJbq/iHYX@YLBfHMzCrMcQMyTbk4K/S74WbTubGaP2KMkS63BDC4j5Obgv@ohNr@Cv4rBWMCagqP@QY768bt5SrstmzwPZudt5U6t0PPaTX@fl0strdzutSrTbtrTZnunckv7ttJ82YlXdIvjZsbqMwr9Yu4/xcrg5VX0iTBkHdy9dX2BWgwHMw6N7ljUYOjRR0MF@68QthCq48n4FF4HLRhT1ewYd@P1H@/6@kVd93/@Aw)

Inputs a non-negative integer in base \$10\$, a pointer to the array of bases, and the array's length (since C pointers don't carry any length info).

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 65 bytes

```
\d+
$*_
+`^(_+),(?>(.*,)?)(\1)+(_*)
$2$1,$#3$*_$.4
(_+,)+(_*)
$.2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYqxDoMwDAV3/wZGspOnKHFopS4w8hOIUKkdujAg/j@NkFhuuLvje/72d@1l3ury8cSukN9WKV4h0yjBQSeVJamX4pTYOIG73D4OA7UPdwlWq@FJhuFiRo70giFFys09YJES4h8) Link includes test cases. Takes `X` as the last argument. Explanation:

```
\d+
$*_
```

Convert to unary.

```
+`^(_+),(?>(.*,)?)(\1)+(_*)
```

Repeat until `X` is less than the first base, divmod `X` by that, and...

```
$2$1,$#3$*_$.4
```

... move the first base to the end, then append the quotient in unary and the remainder in decimal (ironically Retina gives me the quotient in decimal and the remainder in unary...).

```
(_+,)+(_*)
$.2
```

Convert the final digit to decimal. This also handles the `0` case.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 68 bytes

Solved via recursion: we keep storing the modulo, dividing by the base, and drilling down until we hit zero. Then we print each digit on the way back up.

```
f(n,v)=my(m=n%v[1]);n\=v[1];n&&f(n,vector(#v,i,v[i%#v+1]));print1(m)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JczBCoMwEATQe39DlCzdgjFaKCFfkuYgopJD1hBkoV9vk3h7wwwT5@Rfe7yuTRAymPATwVDLVjrQ9DUFmrqu1utyHkk0jB7Z@rbhZ16BjsnTKUWA8vJGOzh43MCxUvXFqlpmf/CeDNkKR5xqKsHBHw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 77 bytes

Returns in list.

```python
def f(x,b,s=[],n=0):
 while x:s,x,n=[x%b[n]]+s,x//b[n],(n+1)%len(b)
 return s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYpBCsMgFET3nuJvAn4iTdrsAp5EXESqRJAfUUPt6a1CVzPz3sRvOS/aWntbB45XYUSWSguSK@4MPqcPFuqeRe1I1cko0nruc1lGFZzmJ07BEjfIINlyJ4LcDpDgqXBP8S4ckQUJagBCcFcC6hb@8pFj8D01i2lcHD8EBMS2rewF2w8)

```python
while x:
```

Keeps self-updating while **X** is larger than the selected element in **[base]**.

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer! Be sure to check out our [Tips for golfing in Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python) page for ways you can golf your program

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 20 bytes

```
Ｆ¬θ0ＷθＦη¿θ«←Ｉ﹪θκ≧÷κθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcuxCsIwFIXhuX2KS6cEIhS76SS6CFbEtXQIbdpcDIlJrnUQnz2GOp6f7wxahsFJk9LkArCrI@Y5h1tAS6yqK74v3xqNgpxhJZoDTuv8lMXf7S5qIgFHGYm1bnwZx7yAB@f5XbTyeYgRZ3vHWRM7WzrhgqPKQIDP4ptS19QCuq2Apu/TZjE/) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｆ¬θ0
```

Special-case an input of `0`.

```
ＷθＦη¿θ«
```

While the input is non-zero, loop over all the bases while the input is non-zero.

```
←Ｉ﹪θκ
```

Output the next digit in reverse order.

```
≧÷κθ
```

Divide by the base.