# Base-ically Guard

Tags: code-golf, number, base-conversion

[Base](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/224730/base-ically-god): part 1

This is part 2, Strongly suggest you go try out the first one if you haven't tried it.

### Story

As one of the solvers, You've managed to get to the door of the base heaven. In front of the door stands the base guard @lyxal, they were angry that you all just left the encoded text on the ground, they demand that you clean (decode) the ground before joining the party, those who are irresponsible get no ticket!

### Task

You will get 2 inputs

- First being `X` which is a non-negative integer in base of base list.
- Second being base which is a list of bases.
- bases range from 1 ~ 10
- The base will contain at least one not `1` base
- answer should be in the base 10

Example:

```
X, [bases] -> answer
110 ,[2] -> 6
30 ,[2,4] -> 6
2100 ,[2,3] -> 30
0 ,[any bases] -> 0
You may want to look at part 1 for more detail
```

## Rule

- No loopholes
- Input/Output in any convenient, reasonable format is accepted.

Satisfy Lyxal with the shortest code, because a long code indicates that you are lazy and not doing your best!

Comment: I approve of this message.

Comment: Can I take the bases and/or the digits in reverse order?

Comment: @hyper-neutrino yes

Comment: Can we take `X` as a list of digits?

Comment: @Adám **Yes** you can

Comment: You should give a test case with more than 2 bases.

Comment: @xigoi, look at part 1, there have more test case

Comment: You should add a test case where the last digit isn't zero.

Comment: [Related, almost dupe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37905/66833) (this is just one half of that, that requires converting from one given base to another, this is converting from a given base to base 10). I'd VTC as this is a subset of that, but I have a hammer

Answer (score 8):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 6 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
⍴⍨∘≢⊥⊢
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=e9S75VHvikcdMx51LnrUtfRR1yIA&f=M1JIUzAEQgMuEwUjINsYyDIGs4xAokCekYIJkGcAAA&i=AwA&r=tryAPL&l=apl-dyalog&m=train&n=f)

An anonymous tacit infix function taking the base in reverse as left argument and `X` as a list of digits as right argument.

`⊢` X

`⊥` evaluated in base…

`⍴⍨∘≢` base cyclically reshaped to the length of `X`

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

Takes the bases in reverse order as the first argument and the digits as the second argument.

```
ṁżṛḅ@ƒ0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzsajex7unP1wR6vDsUkG/w8v13/UtOb//2iu6GijWB2FaEMdQx2D2FgdIN9EByxiDOMbQ/hGIBUIMTMdS5AolG@qY6JjDDHHCKgcKBYLAA)

### Explanation

```
ṁżṛḅ@ƒ0   Main dyadic link
ṁ         Reshape the list of bases like the list of digits
 ż        Zip with
  ṛ         the list of digits
     ƒ0   Reduce with initial value 0 under:
   ḅ        Convert from base
    @         [with swapped arguments]
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
ṁḊ1;×\ḋ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzsaHO7oMrQ9Pj3m4o/v/4eX6j5rW/P8frRBtFKujEG2oowBCsQogjkK0iY4CWNhAR8EYJmaMEDMAqzaCyYDYIIUgSaAYAA)

-1 byte thanks to Jonathan Allan

```
ṁ        Mold bases to the shape/length of the digits, repeating if necessary
 Ḋ       Drop the first base
  1;     and prepend 1 in its place
    ×\   Cumulatively reduce the bases by multiplication
      ḋ  Dot product with the digits
```

Comment: Yes, you are as fast as I expected(5 min)

Comment: This can be golfed to `ṁḊ×\ḋḊ}`.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Wait dot product is one byte? Thanks

Comment: @JonathanAllan unfortunately this doesn't work because in case the last digit isn't zero, it gets ignored

Comment: Oh, I misinterpreted it - so `ṁḊ1;×\ḋ` then, right?

Comment: @JonathanAllan Ah right, that would work. Yes I think that's correct. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 16 bytes

```
JEs*L*F<t*JlQ~hZ
```

[Test suite](http://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=JEs%2aL%2aF%3Ct%2aJlQ%7EhZ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B0%2C1%2C1%5D%0A%5B2%5D%0A%5B0%2C3%5D%0A%5B4%2C2%5D%0A%5B0%2C0%2C1%2C2%5D%0A%5B3%2C2%5D%0A%5B0%5D%0A%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D&debug=0&input_size=2)

Inspired quite heavily by [hyper-neutrino](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68942/hyper-neutrino)['s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225568/78186).

Takes reversed list of digits of X on line 1 and reversed list of bases on line 2 of input.

Explanation:

```
JEs*L*F<t*JlQ~hZ  | Full program
JEs*L*F<t*JlQ~hZQ | with implicit variables
------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------
                  | Call the first line of input Q (implicit)
JE                | Call the second line of input J
    L           Q | Map the following over each d in Q:
     *F           |  Find the product of
       <     ~hZ  |   the first Z (starts at 0, increments with each pass) elements of
         *JlQ     |    J, repeated the length of Q times
        t         |   with the first element removed (product of an empty list is 1)
   *L             |  and multiply it with d
  s               | Sum the resulting list
                  | Print (implicit)
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 8 bytes

```
•Ḣ1p⁽*r*
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=s&code=%E2%80%A2%E1%B8%A21p%E2%81%BD*r*&inputs=%5B0%2C%200%2C%201%2C%202%5D%0A%5B3%2C%202%5D&header=&footer=)

```
•Ḣ1p⁽*r*  Full Program
•         Mold bases like digits
 Ḣ        Pop first base off
  1p      Prepend 1
      r   Cumulative reduce over
    ⁽*    Multiplication
       *  Vectorized multiplication with digits

s (flag)  Sum
```

Comment: Very pleasing. Well done

Comment: Wait, Vyxal was changed within 20 minutes of the challenge being posted?

Comment: @Adám yep. the cumulative-reduce is new

Comment: Wow, cumulative reduce has been in APL for over half a century!

Comment: [9 bytes due to a bug fix inspired by this answer](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=s&code=%E2%80%A20%201%C8%A6%E2%81%BD*r*&inputs=%5B0%2C%200%2C%201%2C%202%5D%0A%5B3%2C%202%5D&header=&footer=)

Comment: [8 bytes too](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=s&code=%E2%80%A2%E1%B8%A21p%E2%81%BD*r*&inputs=%5B0%2C%200%2C%201%2C%202%5D%0A%5B3%2C%202%5D&header=&footer=)

Comment: @lyxal o. nice thanks

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 32 bytes

```hs
(x:y)?(h:t)=x+h*y?(t++[h])
_?_=0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY1BDoIwFET3PcVfuAAppoBxARQu4A0IIST/R4hISalaTo8F2c3Lm8x07fykYVhXz6aLX3pdanxpg@68lJ4JgqqrfdaUjRTrq@1HiYpBZS1H5A1Xqs7Dr9I456fiQebej8RgIANWamrxMr01OaXpQ3omsDbDXQBipv5JucFJ96PxbIlSKu62ufIZbHdrFAmo4hrCAm4sEeCAXw@MI7FJnuycCOYo4o6PhvgB)

The relevant function is `(?)`, which takes as input `X` as a list of digits (least significant first) and the list of bases.

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 35 bytes

```hs
(foldr(\(i,d)n->d+i*n)0.).zip.cycle
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY1BbsIwEEX3PsUsukjaSeSQqhtITsANAFVRZkKtuh7LCWA4fF1D2f2nN/P/1zB/s7Vp6vapmMRSKPaFQSpd1dObeXWlrsv6Znw9XkfL6WcwriNRsIsRifATRQ6b6iKB5s1Lf@RlaxwrsLxA7AIPVPtT4KwCnznMDDGu6SGAaC3/SXKhD8YtxQSU/zrB3I5SKrgPpqbRsFsdoOrhQ7UaMuD7E1eNvktsH9xqlanBzM8L/TtOdjjOqRq9/wM)

Same algorithm in point-free style. Takes the list of digits first and then `X`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <sup>9</sup> 8 bytes

```
δṁ*G*1t¢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9yWhzsbtdy1DEsOLfr//3@0sY5R7P9oAx0DHUMgCwA)

Same idea as hyper-neutrino's answer.

-1 byte from Leo.

Comment: Though, starting from 1 can be a byte shorter (using the base value for `G`) [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9yWhzsbtdy1DEsOLfr//3@0sY5R7P9oAx0DHUMgCwA "Husk – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), <s>60</s> <s>55</s> 52 bytes

```javascript
n=>b=>(g=r=>x in n?g(n[x]+r*b[++x%b.length]):r)(x=0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZvs/z9YuydZOI922yNauQiEzTyHPPl0jL7oiVrtIKylaW7tCNUkvJzUvvSQjVtOqSFOjwtZA839BUWZeiUaaRrShjqGOQaymRrRRrKYmF1zYGCqoY4IibARSDZMyRpGCChqCdfwHAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 90 bytes

```
$
;
+`(\d+,)(.*,)?(\d+)(\d);
$2$1$3;$4
+`(.*,)?(\d+,)(\d+);(\d)
$2$1$.($2*$3*_$4*);
.*,|;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcsxDsIwDAXQ3ecwUpx@VbEdhspDx14CiSLBwMKAGLl7SEBisa3/n5@31/1x0XZI296YgqY9na4TJM0Zso5b@pAgNlb24DrIv4R8SQzzI3Niy@z5zDX3ty7fQa0ZVAsZKnwsh2kptGDk5D0@Qs1IUT4) Link includes test cases. Takes `X` as the last argument. Explanation:

```
$
;
```

Append a marker to keep track of the current digit.

```
+`(\d+,)(.*,)?(\d+)(\d);
$2$1$3;$4
```

Cyclically rotate the list of bases according to the number of digits.

```
+`(.*,)?(\d+,)(\d+);(\d)
$2$1$.($2*$3*_$4*);
```

Cyclically rotate the list of bases back again as each digit is converted from the next base.

```
.*,|;
```

Remove the list of bases and the marker.

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 13 bytes

```
ＩΣＥ⮌θΠ⊞Ｏ…ηκＩι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcuxCoMwEIDhVwlOJ6Rg7eiYuTS0ozgc8SBi2qSXRPDpT2n/@fudR3YRg4jl5VPAYC7wqm@4Y4InbcSZ4NtqZTnO1RWwNftHIsYSGczuAhkfE3it1lP99qX9N4iMTX/tukarsdfqNk1y2cIB) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes `X` as a string. Explanation:

```
    θ           First input (X)
   ⮌            Reversed
  Ｅ             Map over characters
            ι   Current character
           Ｉ    Cast to integer
      ⊞Ｏ        Push to list
         η      Second input (list of bases)
        …       Cyclically chopped to length
          κ     Current index
     Π          Take the product
 Σ              Take the sum
Ｉ               Cast to string
                Implicitly print
```

Although it only takes 1 byte to multiply the current character by the product of the list Charcoal's product returns None for an empty list and it would cost 2 bytes to correct this, so it's easier to push the value to the list so that the product is always defined.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 45 bytes

```javascript
(b,i)=>g=X=>X&&X%10+b[i=b[++i]?i:0]*g(X/10|0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZvtfI0knU9PWLt02wtYuQk0tQtXQQDspOtM2KVpbOzPWPtPKIFYrXSNC39CgxkDzf0FRZl6JRppGtFGspoahoYGmJhdCSMcEKGiMJmYMFDMyNEARBQoB@f8B)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 70 bytes

```c
a;i;r;f(x,b,l)int*b;{for(a=1,r=i=0;x;x/=10)r+=x%10*a,a*=b[i++%l];x=r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZPbjpswEIbv8xQjJCQMjhZzWGnX6/ai6lMkqOJgttbS7ApHqtWIV286YCA43Ugw8f/NP/KMhnr/WtfXa8kV73kbGFrRjqjTOaz4pX3vg1Iw2gslYm64eRAsJn0kjM/isKRlKKqDiiK/K7gRPR@uHz1ag9FeUsAAHYELYB0YRVAgIOYYXqDjEEWKwORoA8/XfuPRQH31KHjPnkcolAdVEA7DbrT@KtUpILvLDvA3Cmepz/GhwIqXZOCrxGaJZhsxWcR0I6ZWfKJbe2bFlGY038i5Iy93CCemLZvuQ@0dbEhsSG3IbNjYp/OPztq1@iPf22CqQh7mU2iPFDaUuZS5NHFp4tLUpalLM5dmLs1dmpP7RoxthDGcQopPwmJ8MxwGS3AU8SZfmg9Zn2VjHY8UHq1ltCbxLbf@WfYhvmX9JntMhjHdO5rvydE8fcMnH7dlc0692XlbuVMjzbx209@XpanlEre@VmXazTEbt3cqt1x8rDQ3O/GCb3FYzVh/RqFbzN2nWCNePkCXSCTryO6t6wfUUDjgOAy5Y0FFoSP/GwrYfwG/AV8fT@jTdB20FEIXs2PYDde/dduVr/q6//0P)

Inputs a non-negative integer in base 10, a pointer to the array of bases, and the array's length (since C pointers don't carry any length info).